# Bind Event to Dynamically Created Element in Object Oriented Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a Javascript class that is dynamically created.

PostCard is dynamically created from Ajax. Because it is dynamically created, after ajax load, the this.$propose_button will not be clicked.

```
var PostCard = function($root) {
    this.$root = $root;
    this.stuff_id = this.$root.data('stuff_id');
    this.id = this.$root.data('id');
    this.is_owner = this.$root.data('is_owner');
    this.$propose_button = null;
    this.$favorite_button = null;
    this.$total_favorite = null;
    this.$image_view_editor = null;
    this.image_view_editor = null;
    this.$proposal_box_modal = null;
    this.proposal_box = null;
    this.$proposal_box = null;
    this.init();
    this.initEvents();
};

PostCard.prototype.initEvents = function() {
    var self =this;
    this.$propose_button.on("click", function(e) {
        if(self.is_owner ) {
            return false;
        }   
        if(CommonLibrary.isGuest()) {
            return false;
        }
        self.$proposal_box_modal.modal("show").load($(this).attr("value"));

    });
}
```

PostCard is dynamically created in PostList class.

```
var PostList = function($root) {
    this.$root = $root;
    this.stuff_ids = '';
    this.id = $root.data('id');
    this.location = $root.data('location');
    this.query = '';
    this.post_cards = [];
    this.$post_list_area = null;
    this.permit_retrieve_post = true;
    this.init();
    this.initEvents();
};
```

It has a method that if it is fired, it will dynamically load PostCard class

```
PostList.prototype.retrievePostWhenScroll_ = function(e) {
    var self = e.data.self;
    var scrollPercentage = 
            ((document.documentElement.scrollTop + document.body.scrollTop) / 
            (document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight) * 100);
    if(scrollPercentage > PostList.prototype.SCROLL_VALUE) {
        if(self.permit_retrieve_post) {
            self.permit_retrieve_post = false;
            $.ajax({
                url: $("#base-url").val() + "/site/get-more-posts",
                type: 'post',
                data: {'ids' : self.stuff_ids, query: self.query, location: self.location},
                success: function(data) {
                    var parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
                    if(parsedData['status'] === 1) {
                        self.$post_list_area.append(parsedData['view']);
                        $(parsedData['view']).filter('.post-card').each(function(index, value) {
                            self.post_cards.push(new PostCard($(value)));
                            self.stuff_ids += "," + $(value).data('stuff_id');
                        });
                    }
                    self.permit_retrieve_post = true;
                },
                error : function(data) {
                    self.permit_retrieve_post = true;

                }
            });   
        }
    }

};
```

I want to know a solution without $(document).on(event, selector, callback) -because the class attribute has to be preserved.
if $(document) is used, it cannot detect the attribute in PostCard class.

The solution where the event is attached directly to element is preferred, but i also accept other feasible solutions

Answer (score 0):

Try this ;)

There are two ways to do this:

**1. delegate events:**

**2. Bind events in ajax response**

You can choose any but 2nd is preferred. In `ajax` response after `self.$post_list_area.append(parsedData['view']);` this statement you can bind events to DOM elements;

Comment: i have bind the event inside new PostCard(), the postcard contain this.$propose_button event